# Web scraping with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension for whatsapp.

When i'm trying to store all the div objects of all the chats in a list. The page dosen't load all the chats, only about 10 at a time.
When you scroll Down the rest of the chats are update in the html of the page.

Is there a proper method to extract all the divs without the need to scroll little by little and add it all to a list ?

Comment: What tool are you using for scraping?

Comment: I don't understand what tool. I'm creating google extension with JS chrome manifest v3.

Comment: There's no universal method. You'll have to either 1) scroll and use MutationObserver or 2) investigate the site's network requests and then make your own request to get the data.

Comment: Oh, ok i will look into those methods. Thanks.